# Cannot give permissions to sign-in to my app, error "App needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant"

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm using OpenID Connect to authenticate users according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc. I registered application in Azure AD and there are following user consents defined:

[image]

The problem is that only 3 users are authenticated while others get error 90094 with message:

> Need admin approval
>
> App needs permission to access resources in your organisation that
> only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

These 3 users who can sign-in are the ones who granted "Sign users in" and "Sign in and read profile" permissions (visible under "Granted By" column links on the screenshot) and this is the only difference in Azure configuration between them and the rest who cannot sign-in. All of users have been added to app through "Users and groups" page with the same roles. All users are from the same company's directory. Api permissions looks like following

[image]

Moreover I have setting

[image]

I don't know how to grant permissions to other users and I don't know how to extend list of permissions visible on the screenshot.
Any ideas?

I wonder if any changes in Azure Portal happened since November 2019 when I created and configured that app. There where no changes in my permissions since that time, so I didn't have more power that time. I've read various documentation on MSDN about consents and permissions but didn't find solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not the admin of your Azure AD tenant.

Please see this reference: [Disable or enable user consent from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#disable-or-enable-user-consent-from-the-azure-portal).

I see that you have the setting: **Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf**. But if you don't [Enable the admin consent workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow), when the application is requesting permissions that the user is not allowed to grant, the users still can't consent to the apps by themselves.

Another method is that you need to use an admin account to log into Azure portal. And then grant admin consent for your tenant.

[image]

Comment: Your response is reasonable, but I still don't understand how these 3 users (including me) were able to get access if we didn't request it. When I register another app and try to sign-in through it then I don't have permissions too. It looks like something has been changed for last 2 months (in portal itself or in our AAD settings) as these 3 users have access for 2 months already. "Admin consent request (preview)" pane is disabled for me as I'm not an admin.

Comment: @szalafe Yes. The portal feature is updated often. I'm not sure why and when the changes happen. But currently you need an admin to help you to complete the configuration.

Comment: I found backdoor which is opened until end of February 2020 - legacy app registration. If I register app this way I'm able to grant permissions to Azure Active Directory for all app users. A bit strange to have two features working in parallel having different security options.

Comment: @szalafe It's not a back door. In the legacy experience you were only consenting for yourself, not for everyone (unless you are an admin). The new experience only offers the option to consent on behalf of the whole tenant, but that doesn't mean you're not allowed to consent for yourself (e.g. if you sign in to the app in question)--there's just no button to do it directly from the app registration. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950232/how-is-the-grant-permissions-button-in-legacy-azure-ad-app-registration-differ